# Displaying x & y coordinate with mouse handler

Tags: racket

"Pictured Programs" [http://www.facom.ufu.br/~marcelo/PF/pictures_racket.pdf](http://www.facom.ufu.br/%7Emarcelo/PF/pictures_racket.pdf) Ch.10 (final exercise 10.2.6) is the book I'm working out of.

I'm trying to use what has been introduced in the book in a linear fashion. The exercise wants an animation that displays the x & y coordinates on the window.

This must be done **without** conditionals, loops, built-in functions not mentioned, & etc...

I'm having trouble writing the mouse-handler handling the x-mouse & y-mouse in the same expression.

I can't think of a way to track them both (ie... [I need a space between the two coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUtly.png) in the same mh without throwing an error.

```
(define (number->image s)
  (text (string-append "(" (number->string s)")" "("(number->string s)   ")" ) 18 "blue"))

(define (show-coord s)
  (number->image s)))
 
(define (mh s mouse-x mouse-y me)
   (string->number (string-append
                    (number->string mouse-x)
                    (number->string mouse-y))))

(define (string-world s)
  (big-bang s 
    (check-with number?)
    (on-draw show-coord 200 200)
    (on-mouse mh)))

(string-world 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a number from the mouse handler, how about returning a list of coordinates? Then the list of coordinates can be converted to an appropriate string representation before calling `text`.

Since the world state is now a list instead of a number, the `check-with` predicate will need to be changed:

```racket
#lang racket
(require picturing-programs)

(define (coord->image s)
  (text (string-append "("
                       (number->string (first s))
                       " "
                       (number->string (second s))
                       ")")
        18 "blue"))

(define (show-coord s)
  (coord->image s))
 
(define (mh s mouse-x mouse-y me)
  (list mouse-x mouse-y))

(define (string-world s)
  (big-bang s 
    (check-with list?)
    (on-draw show-coord 200 200)
    (on-mouse mh)))

(string-world '(0 0))
```

### Update

OP says that lists have not been introduced in the book yet. OK. We need some way to return the information that we want to display. Let's just return a string! Don't forget that the `check-with` predicate and the initial world state must match our new approach:

```racket
#lang racket
(require picturing-programs)

(define (coord->image s)
  (text s 18 "blue"))

(define (show-coord s)
  (coord->image s))
 
(define (mh s mouse-x mouse-y me)
  (string-append "("
                 (number->string mouse-x)
                 " "
                 (number->string mouse-y)
                 ")"))

(define (string-world s)
  (big-bang s 
    (check-with string?)
    (on-draw show-coord 200 200)
    (on-mouse mh)))

(string-world "")
```

Comment: I like your approach, but the exercise is based off of previous knowledge learned in the book and lists have not been used yet.

Comment: @WonderingMinds -- Well, you can construct a string in the mouse handler and return that for the world state. I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: I think this is the best answer for what I was looking for in this exercise for now.